# TargetNameSpace usage for xmlSchema Hindesrs XML Validation against XMLSchema

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I was Validating My XML against XMLSchema , If i assign any targetnamespace it will throw errors.

my code is as below.

```
string 
ab="<HostName>Arasanalu</HostName><AdminUserName>Administrator</AdminUserName>
    <AdminPassword>A1234</AdminPassword><PlaceNumber>38</PlaceNumber>"


        try
        {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
       // settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);


        //settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema","ab1.xml");

        settings.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(@"<xs:schema  xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" targetNamespace=""root"">
                                                            <xs:element name=""root"" type=""RootElementType""/>
                                                             <xs:complexType name=""RootElementType"">
                                                              <xs:sequence>
                                                             <xs:any  minOccurs=""1"" maxOccurs=""unbounded"" processContents=""lax""/>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                         </xs:schema>
                                                          <bp:root xmlns:bp=""myNamespace"">
                                                          <parameters>ab</parameters>
                                                           </bp:root>
                                                            </root>")));


          // Create the XmlReader object.
                XmlReader xmlrdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<root>" + ab+ "</root>"),settings);

                // Parse the file. 
                while (xmlrdr.Read()) ;
```

it was throwing error:

```
  ex = {"Type 'RootElementType' is not declared."}
```

if I remove TargetNamespace it will work fine if i provide processContents=""lax"" for any element.

please let me know how can make my targetnamespace usage correctly inorder to work(so that i can remove processContents=""lax""  as it takes default "strict" for particularnamespaece.)

Regards,
Channa

Comment: What is the content of `ab`?

Comment: @ Alex: I have added info for string ab , Thats my xml string.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `xmlns="root"` to both `xs:schems` and `xs:element`:

```
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            targetNamespace="root" 
            xmlns="root">
  <xs:element name="root" type="RootElementType" 
              xmlns="root"/>
```

Could be related to this MS article: [BUG: Type "###" is not declared in reference to local type of an included XSD Schema file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317611).

Comment: Thanks But it did not worked as required for me. if i send any inavlid for my string ab as <ElementA />ABC<ElementB /> it should throw XmlSchemaValidationException  but is passed straight away.